# Android keypair generation

Tags: java, android, openssl, bouncycastle

`OpenSsl` generates a private key in `DER` format with 118 bytes length. (`openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 and so on`).

In android `KeyPairGenerator` initialized like:

```
 KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "SC");
            ECGenParameterSpec spec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256k1");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(spec, new SecureRandom());
            return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
```

returns a private key with a 144 length. But i need 118. Where is a difference? Is smh added in android implementation? How could i get 118 key length? Cannot find implementation to figure out.

Comment: Crypto software produces keys in various formats for storage, interoperability, etc. Java (and Android Java) exports private keys using the format specified by PKCS#8. What format do you need?

Comment: Which format is generated by that command?
openssl ec -in test.pem -outform DER -out der.der

Comment: it showing Caused by: java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: SC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a way to do this.
Generate key pair:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "SC");
            ECGenParameterSpec spec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256k1");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(spec, new SecureRandom());
           KeyPair kp =  keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
```

Get private key bytes array:

```
byte[] privateK = kp.getPrivate();
```

Then convert private key to **PKCS1**:

```
 byte[] privBytes = privateKey.getEncoded();
            PrivateKeyInfo pkInfo = PrivateKeyInfo.getInstance(privBytes);
            ASN1Encodable encodable = pkInfo.parsePrivateKey();
            ASN1Primitive primitive = encodable.toASN1Primitive();
            byte[] privBytesEncoded =  primitive.getEncoded();
```

Comment: "SC" is a provider?

Comment: @AnQuocDuyNguyen yes, spongycastle provider

Comment: it showing  Caused by: java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: SC

Comment: ECGenParameterSpec spec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256k1"); this line giving error

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit of good news/bad news. The good news is that the bytes you want are a subsequence of the bytes returned by `PrivateKey.getEncoded()`. The bad news is that there's no good way that I'm aware of to get at them. Well, there is one easy way: the bytes you want are always at the end of `PrivateKey.getEncoded()`, so if you know the length of the byte sequence is *n* (e.g. 118 in your example) then just take the last *n* bytes of `PrivateKey.getEncoded()`.

A slightly harder way is to parse through the encoding using the Spongycastle/Bouncycastle ASN1 routines, as in the following snippet:

```
private static byte[] encodePrivateKey(PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception{
    ASN1InputStream asn1InputStream = new ASN1InputStream(privateKey.getEncoded());
    ASN1Primitive asn1Primitive = asn1InputStream.readObject();
    DLSequence seq = (DLSequence) asn1Primitive;
    ASN1OctetString octetString = (ASN1OctetString) seq.getObjectAt(2);
    return octetString.getOctets();
}
```

I offer this as an example but I have to warn you that this is brittle: I haven't made any real effort to follow the PKCS#8 specification, I just eyeballed the ASN.1 structure to grab the bytes I knew were needed.